# document.getElementById('').src doesn't change the image in Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
<img src="img/icon_001.png"class="nodesImages" id="nodo179"/>
```

but I need to change the image with a `if` statement:

```
if (alarma179 == "1") {
    document.getElementById('nodo179').src = "img/icon_007.png";
}
```

With Firefox there's no problem but with Chrome and IE the image doesn't change. Do you know if there's a way to make browsers support this functionality or is there any other way to change the image?

Comment: look into alarma179 to be 1

Comment: This should be working if `alarma179=="1"` is `true`. This could be another problem, please provide the error message from the console, and any other relevant code if necessary. Also ensure that the element exist when this code executes, wrapping it in a `document.ready` or `window.load`.

Comment: Is your JavaScript code in the `head` section? Is the variable defined and value set to 1? Add complete code in question

Comment: There's nothing here that would behave differently between Firefox and IE/Chrome. There's most likely something else that's been excluded. Please post more code and open your browser's developer console to look for errors.

Answer (score 0):

The code provided works for me,too. So, maybe your IE and Chrome are blocking JS. (You can check this easily by going to (http://activatejavascript.org/) ) To unblock, you have to adjust some settings in your browsers. On the same site, you can find explanations how to do that.

Alternatively, in IE, you can refresh the page (F5) and then click on the button 'Allow blocked content' in the bottom.

In Chrome, you can allow/block JS in Chrome's Settings. Click: Settings > Show advanced settings... > Privacy > Content settings > JavaScipt section. Same explanation also here:(https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/BYOQskiuGU0).

Comment: Make sure your id values in JS and in HTML are matching. (I had to put it here, because I cannot add comments to other people's answer yet).

Comment: I enabled ins javascript and works in IE but Chrome does not work, I have also executed the page in another Mozilla browser and does not work so I think it is linked with versions of browsers think it would help me if you know another way to change the image. Thanks! Firefox 40.0.2 dont working, Chrome 43.0.2357.124 don't working, Firefox Developer 40.0a2 don't working.

Comment: Strange behavior... I updated my Firefox to 40.0.2 and it works. But, if I disable JS in Firefox, it won't work. 
I know that I am a bit annoying with this, but try to enable JS in Firefox. Go to adress bar of FIrefox, type "about:config" (without quotes), and then in the search bar type "javascript.enabled", check its state and if you click twice on that row, you can edit the value (true/false). Change it & check again.
On the link I provided, there is an explanation how to activate JS in Firefox (again here: [http://activatejavascript.org/en/instructions/firefox#instructions] ). I tried

Comment: Another idea... Maybe you have some extension/add-on/plug-in in your browser which is blocking JS...